# Ruby: Using split and regex

Tags: ruby, regex, split

I am trying to take in a line of text as follows:

```
1 | Company 1234 Anywhere St, SJ (12.34567, -98.765432)
```

and isolate the first number and the two floats.

I have been playing with a RegEx creator and came up with the following:
To get the first integer: `(\\d+)`
To get the floats: `([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])`

But when I use these with .split I am getting `"syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting ')'"`

Any insight would be great!

Comment: Show your actual source code.

Comment: Helpful answers were provided below, but I'm really curios as to what caused that error. I've never seen ruby complain about `$undefined` before.

Answer (score 0):

```
input = '1 | Company 1234 Anywhere St, SJ (12.34567, -98.765432)'
regexp = /^\s*(\d+)\s*\|.*\(([+-]?\d*\.\d+),\s*([+-]?\d*\.\d+)/
md = input.match(regexp)
```

md[1], md[2], md[3] are your desired values, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

```
"1 | Company 1234 Anywhere St, SJ (12.34567, -98.765432)"
.sub(/.*\|/, "")
.scan(/-?[\d.]+/)
# => ["1234", "12.34567", "-98.765432"]
```